# How can I remove a space from a text file?

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file with spaces ("= ") to delete. What can I do? The text is as follows: " Cayce fundó la _As= ociación para la Investigación y la Iluminación (ARE) sin fines de lucro en 1931, = para explorar la espiritualidad, la salud holística, la intuición= , la interpretación de los sueños, el desarrollo psíquico, l= a reencarnación y los misterios antiguos, todos temas que surgen con f= recuencia en los más de 14,000 lecturas psíquicas do= cumentadas dadas por Cayce."

Comment: See any online tutorial on using `sed`

Comment: For something this simple, I'd just do it in my text editor with the find/replace function. I'd search for "= " and replace it with "=" (assuming that's what you're asking for) using the *replace all* feature after verifying that it worked on the first one or two. There are surely innumerable ways to do this. If you wanted to replace the entire "= " string then you'd just replace it with nothing, leaving that space blank.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is:

```
sed -i 's/= //g' file
```